# python datetime mistake - wrong year of 1970

Tags: python, datetime

Can anyone help to explain: why does setting unit = 'ms' make the year as 1970?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt1 =  pd.to_datetime(1574846518.25088,unit='s')
print('dt1' , dt1)
dt2 =  pd.to_datetime(1574846518.25088,unit='ms')
print('dt2' , dt2)
```

Out:

```
dt1 2019-11-27 09:21:58.250880003
dt2 1970-01-19 05:27:26.518250880
```

Comment: Well… 1574846518.25088 *seconds* since Jan 1st 1970 and 1574846518.25088 ***milliseconds*** since Jan 1st 1970 will lead to different results…

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just math, a second is 1000ms, so setting the unit as `ms` makes like you take the value in second and divide by 1000, which make a very lower value, *18227 days* becomes *18 days*

```
value = 1574846518

print(value, 's')  # 1574846518 s
print(value // 60, 'm')  # 26247441 m
print(value // 3600, 'h')  # 437457 h
print(value // 86400, 'd')  # 18227 d
print(value // (86400 * 365), 'y')  # 49 y

print()

print(value, 'ms')  # 1574846518 ms
print(value // 1000, 's')  # 1574846 s
print(value // 60000, 'm')  # 26247 m
print(value // 3600000, 'h')  # 437 h
print(value // 86400000, 'd')  # 18j
```